# Move content from folder one level up (into parent directory)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have numerous folders from which I want to move the entire content into their parent folder.

```
d:\folder1\foo\[files1-10]
d:\folder2\foo\[files11-14]
d:\folder3\bar\[files1-9]
..
d:\folder178\foo\file15
```

this should end up like this:

```
d:\foo\[files1-15]
d:\bar\[files1-9]
```

The folders "folder1", "folderX" etc can contain subdirectories of the same name (like foo), but those contain unique filenames.

How can I conveniently move the content of the subdirectories to d:\  ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the command-line preprocessor and to issue `MOVE *.* ..` operating system commands so that you move all of your files where you need them.

Eventually, you also end up issuing your last `MOVE foo\ ..` and `MOVE bar\ ..` operating system commands so that you move them into your root `D:\` folder.

Here you have an example:

`CD D:\folder1\foo\`

`MOVE *.* ..`

`CD ..`

`MOVE foo\ ..`

`CD ..\folder2\foo\`

`MOVE *.* D:\foo\`

and so on.